# Can I navigate to an ionic page from an ionic component?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, mobile, web-applications, ionic3

I am developing an application with Ionic Framework. It is possible that it grows rapidly, and I would like to learn to modulate and correctly reuse pages, components, etc.

Therefore, this question arose, which I can not resolve by my own means:
Is it possible to call a modal or a page (using NavController) from a component?

Suppose we have a page. Within it, I want to use several reusable components.

Any page:

```
<ion-content>
   <my-component-1> </ my-component-1>
   <my-component-2> </ my-component-2>
</ ion-content>
```

For example, my-component-1 should be a button that sends us to another page or modal.

- And what if I want to use lazy loading and avoid the "No component
  factory found for MyPage"?
- In which module should I declare my pages?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic implementation:

**.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
// import your pages

@Component({...})
export class SomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  openComponentOne(){
    this.navCtrl.push(FirstPage)
    // OR
    // this.navCtrl.setRoot(OnePage)
  }

  openComponentTwo(){
    this.navCtrl.push(SecondPage)
    // OR
    // this.navCtrl.setRoot(SecondPage)
  }
}
```

**.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button (click)="openComponentOne()">
    Component One
  </button>
  <button ion-button (click)="openComponentTwo()">
    Component Two
  </button>
</ion-content>
```